# Hyperledger Fabric 1.4: Error Instantiating Chaincode (Node) with Internet Connectivity

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ibm-blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

The problem in hand is that we want to deploy a blockchain network on a server that is not connected to the internet.

When Instantiating the chaincode on a Peer it fails as it requires the fabric-shim package to be downloaded which is used for the chaincode. The logs for it can be found below.

Is there any workaround it or can we bundle the npm packages and when instantiating the chaincode point the fabric to use that bundle as a directory for npm modules?

[image: Error Logs]

Comment: i think it should work if you bundle it beforehand. Have you tried it?

Comment: @guoger we ended up using GO chaincode instead. Bundling all packages was not so feasible.